# How to solve corrupted file pdf, if pdf generate from java code?

Tags: java, pdf, buffer, inputstream, fileinputstream

i am using java language for function generate pdf report, but my report from jasper. The java code will run through scheduler, which is my pdf report will generate automatically by server scheduler in early morning. The problem is, some of my pdf that have been generate was not be able to open. It is corrupt. Not all pdf facing this problem, only one or two pdf will be corrupted.

The below code is the part, where my pdf will be generate.

```
public static void saveFileFromUrlWithJavaIO(String fileName, String fileUrl)
        throws MalformedURLException, IOException {
    BufferedInputStream in = null;
    FileOutputStream fout = null;

    try {
        in = new BufferedInputStream(new URL(fileUrl).openStream());
        fout = new FileOutputStream(fileName);

        byte data[] = new byte[1024];
        int count;
        while ((count = in.read(data, 0, 1024)) != -1) {
            fout.write(data, 0, count);

        }
        fout.flush();
        logger.debug("ADD FLUSH");
    }catch(IOException e) {

        logger.debug("For exception: {}", e);
    }catch(Exception e) {
        logger.debug("For exception 123: {}", e);
    }  finally {
        if (in != null) {
            in.close();
        }
        if (fout != null) {
            fout.close();
        }
    }
}
```

For information, i already inserted flush into the code, but the file still corrupt.
Anyone can help me, i really appreciate. 
Thank you

Comment: Please share such a broken pdf file for analysis.

Comment: I dont know how to share the file here,but i can tell the error while opening the pdf. The error shows 'adobe reader could not open the file because it is either not supported file type or because the file has been damaged'.
Only a few file will be corrupted. But when i run it manually, the pdf file will generate and not corrupted as per run by scheduler.Any idea to fix my code to prevent my file turn to corrupt while generate? So after the scheduler run to generate the pdf, the pdf will be fine to open.

Comment: The first thing to do is to check *in which way* they are damaged. This may help in determining *why* they are damaged to eventually fix this. You share files here by putting them onto a public file share (e.g. on googledrive or dropbox, please don't use file sharing platforms that drown the downloader in ads or trojans) and posting the URL here.

Comment: Hi, I already insert it into gdrive.
here is the link
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1JA2KoFzU16SXE6Z8LtPb0i7VTZPg1dZV/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

The reason why you cannot open those "PDF files" in a PDF viewer (at least in case of your example file) is that *the file is **no PDF** file* to start with, it is a HTML file!

More exactly it is *TIBCO Jaspersoft: JasperReports Server Error Page* showing

> #### Error Message
>
> There was an error on the server. Try again or contact site administrators. (Error UID: fcefabf1-6158-4549-969c-25c9ec4f9ba2)

Very likely, therefore, sometimes the generation of your scheduled reports either fails or has simply not finished yet when your Java code tries to retrieve the report.

Comment: Ooo i see. so means that from my java code,i didnt need to change is it? So i need to change my jasper code,is it?

Comment: I don't know what exactly caused the "error on the server". But indeed, apparently you don't need to change the Java code above but either your scheduling or something on the Jasper side. Nonetheless you can of course add a sanity check to the Java-code: if the report file you downloaded starts with "%PDF-", it most likely is ok; otherwise there most likely was a problem. In the latter case you may probably trigger some signal for yourself.

Comment: Hi can you please help me : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60738068/itext-embedding-color-space-icc-profile-in-pdf-images

Comment: @Nur Has my answer resolved your question? In that case please consider marking the answer as accepted (i.e. click the tick at its upper left).