# iText embedding Color space (ICC Profile) in PDF Images

Tags: java, pdf, itext, itext7

I am using iText-7 java library to generate pdf using below code.
(I am adding image to pdf doc)

```
 pdf = new PdfDocument(writer);
 Document document = new Document(pdf);

 ImageData data = ImageDataFactory.create(imgfilepath);

 Image img = new Image(data);
 img.scaleToFit(imageWidth, imageHeight);

 img.setFixedPosition(1, 0, 0);
 document.add(img);
```

-Using same Image i have created PDF from acrobat.

**Problem :**

(1) When i print above 2 PDFs- 1 created using iText, 2- created using Acrobat - i see quality different in print.

- So i did research and come to know about there is something related iCC profile (color profile) which need to bind.

When i check metadata of both the PDFs i come to know there is some difference in Color Space property of PDF.( i have checked meta data here : https://www.metadata2go.com)

***ITEXT PDF METADATA DETAIL:***

[image]

***Acrobat PDF METADATA DETAIL***

[image]

**So My Questions**

(1) How can i get same quality like Acrobat using iText when print in CMYK Machine (ex.indigo)?

(2) Is There any Way to attach color profile(Color Space) to image in PDF? (currently what i have tried looks not working)

You can check both PDFs Here:

(1) [PDF Created Using Acrobat](https://creativeapps.sgp1.digitaloceanspaces.com/Acrobat%20PDF.pdf)
(2) [PDF Created Using iText](https://creativeapps.sgp1.digitaloceanspaces.com/iText%20Generated%20PDF.pdf)

Here some more information from iText RUPS:

iText Generated PDF Details

[image: iText Generated PDF Details]

Acrobat Generated PDF :
[image]

Answer (score 0):

It seems that if the image is manipulated, the ICC profile is lost.

I used the PdfCanvas api to add an image taken from iPhone to the PDF, it looks good to me.

```
    @Test
    public void testImageColorSpace() throws Exception {

        String imageWithIcc = resourceFile("image-ios-profile.jpg");
        String destination = targetFile("image-colorspace-itext-pdfcanvas.pdf");
        
        PdfDocument pdfDocument = new PdfDocument(new PdfWriter(destination));
        PdfPage page = pdfDocument.addNewPage(new PageSize(mm2pt(400f), mm2pt(400f)));

        PdfCanvas pdfCanvas = new PdfCanvas(page);
        
        ImageData imageData = ImageDataFactory.create(imageWithIcc);

        AffineTransform at = AffineTransform.getTranslateInstance(mm2pt(100f), mm2pt(100f));
        at.concatenate(AffineTransform.getScaleInstance(mm2pt(200f), mm2pt(200f)));
        float[] matrix = new float[6];
        at.getMatrix(matrix);

        pdfCanvas.addImage(imageData, matrix[0], matrix[1], matrix[2], matrix[3], matrix[4], matrix[5]);
        pdfDocument.close();
    }
```

[image]